# Android LibGDX Mobile cores

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am changing x coordinate every time when when render method is called.Is it working faster on 4 core than on 1 core ? I have tested it on Alcatel Snap (4 core 1.2Ghz) and Xperia X 10 (1 core) .And does it mean that on 1 core fps is smaller than on 4 core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libgdx logic and rendering runs in a single thread if you dont spawn your own threads. That means that at least your logic and rendering runs in one thread which *works on a single core*. (*It is not quit correct that a thread runs on one core but it is not paralell so there is no effect to it if you have more cores*) So if your logic is in a single thread it doesnt matter if you have 4 or 8 or one 1 core. Well it is not like that exactly because libgdx does spwan some more threads for other stuff but in principal your logic and rendering should be like that.

So if you change your x position every frame the core number does not have any effect **BUT** it has an effect if your device is to slow to hold the 60fps. Moreover some devices have less than 60fps at their vsync state so some devices would play your game slower than other devices.

**As always recommended change your position depending on the delta time instead of the frames!**

for example something like this:

```
this.setPosition(getX() + direction.x * delta * this.velocity, getY() + direction.y * delta * this.velocity);
```

This does change the position value depending on the **delta** velocity and the direction. So if the delta is higher because the device has a lower framerate the movement stays the same.

Comment: libgdx handles the fps for you. Depending on the hardware it will try fixing it on 60 or 30 fps.

Comment: @Juan This is not correct. It has automatically set vsync to true. On desctop you can disable this on phone you cant. Moreover some Phones run on different fps max values with vsync! And no if your logic is to slow to run in 60fps on that system you wont have 60fps if you dont spawn a thread for the logic of your game and seperate the rendering from the logic. (For example if you use a A* algorithm for the movement)

Comment: About using delta, please check this answer to make sure your objects don't get updated with a too large value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995854/how-to-track-time-in-libgdxandroid/23996041#23996041