# Opening LibGDX project in Eclipse (ADT Bundle)

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

Currently using [ADT Bundle for Windows](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for developing Android applications.
It has built-in a Eclipse IDE, and is easy and ready to use. (Just extract the .zip, no installing required)

However, I want to develop a [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) project using that Eclipse IDE.
I have successfully generated a libGDX project using [gdx-setup.jar](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle).
To import this generated project to Eclipse, [this libGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Eclipse) says that in Eclipse IDE I should go to

> File -> Import -> Gradle -> Gradle Project

But I don't find any `Gradle` in the `Import` window, here's the screenshot:

[image: There's no "Gradle"]

I tried importing it using `Existing Android Code Into Workspace`. But it has multiple errors.

I also found the [Eclipse Integration Gradle](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/) and [Spring Tool Suite](http://spring.io/tools/sts)
I can't figure out how they works and how to install them.
Please tell me how can I install those plugins.
If there's a step-by-step guide to develop a libGDX project in Eclipse IDE (ADT Bundle), that would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you're looking for is the Eclipse Gradle Integration Tool which you can add to Eclipse as a module.

To do this, you must go to Help -> Install New Software -> Add -> specify name such as 'Gradle', and add the following location: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle

This will install Gradle integration module into your ADT, and you'll be able to import the project.

A tutorial that I liked by the way on LibGDX was the following: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Tutorial-series.aspx

**EDIT:** The new ADT 23.0.2 does not allow installing it directly, you need to go to Help -> Install New Software -> Work With -> Juno -> General Purpose Tools -> Marketplace Client, and then search for Gradle and add the Gradle Integration tool (not the 4.4 one).

Comment: Afterwards, it's fairly straightforward to develop, although the new project structure extends from the ApplicationAdapter, rather than from Game. The key difference is that for Game, you can set an active Screen to which all events are delegated, thus allowing modularity in your program. If you need any more help, ask me freely - albeit as I said, I didn't use scene2d nor scene2d.ui, but rather created my own "widgets".

Comment: Here was a question on time processing with LibGDX, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995854/how-to-track-time-in-libgdxandroid/23996041#23996041

Comment: You're welcome :D How's it going? it's been a week, I hope you've made progress :) LibGDX is awesome.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. Actually (and luckily) this game project is still pending, so now I'm working on a different project. With more time, I'm quite sure I will use LibGDX. Now I'm still learning how to use LibGDX properly. Its nice that there are 5 sample games from LibGDX's wiki site, I've downloaded them all. Anyway, thanks for asking! :)