# Libgdx 1.3.0 doesn't build eclipse files

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

I saw that version 1.3.0 of libgdx was available so I got it and when I use the project setup to setup a project I check advanced > build for eclipse and hit generate but when I try to import it into eclipse it says no projects found. Version 1.2.0 worked perfectly for me before 1.3.0 was released now I can't even get that version to build eclipse files.  Any fixes and I don't use gradle.

Comment: looking at ur reputation its silly to ask. Did u correctly import the root directory which was generated after libgdx setup

Comment: You should probably just start using the Gradle Integration Tool to import the project.

Comment: Yes i did it the same way I imported 1.2.0 projects but now that won't work either.

Comment: I am pretty sure you used the `Import existing projects into workspace`. Try installing the Gradle Integration Tool and import it as a Gradle project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031573/opening-libgdx-project-in-eclipse-adt-bundle

Comment: in that case, I posted an answer which can be accepted if that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing the projects as Gradle projects. To do that, do the following:
[Opening LibGDX project in Eclipse (ADT Bundle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031573/opening-libgdx-project-in-eclipse-adt-bundle?lq=1)

The new ADT 23.0.2 does not allow installing the Gradle Integration Tool directly, you need to go to Help -> Install New Software -> Work With -> Juno -> General Purpose Tools -> Marketplace Client, and then search for Gradle and add the Gradle Integration tool (not the 4.4 one).

Then just use Import -> Gradle, press Build Model, then OK and it should work.