# How to Import Gradle Project into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-gradle-plugin

I am finding it hard to run the gradle sample projects in Android Studio, getting lots of errors, found solutions for few errors in stackoverflow but its killing most of my time, Most of the new libraries are built using gradle, is there a way i can convert the gradle  so that i can import in eclipse like general android-eclipse project? i tried the tutorial posted [here](http://codetutr.com/2013/03/23/how-to-import-gradle-project-into-eclipse/)

but most of the time its not working, i wanna try New material design samples available form github , can some help me importing them in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try installing gradle integration to Eclipse from here: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle
You can choose only gradle during installation. Then Import / Gradle project, select root folder and press "Build model" for getting list of gradle projects. After selecting your project it will generate eclipse project file and import it. Then you can use your projects as usual (build, run etc).

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote down here as it was relevant for LibGDX projects, [Libgdx 1.3.0 doesn't build eclipse files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243615/libgdx-1-3-0-doesnt-build-eclipse-files/25246284#25246284)

The new ADT 23.0.2 does not allow installing the Gradle Integration Tool directly from  http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle (or at least it did not for me), you need to go to Help -> Install New Software -> Work With -> Juno -> General Purpose Tools -> Marketplace Client, and then search for Gradle and add the Gradle Integration tool (not the 4.4 one).

Then just use Import -> Gradle, press Build Model, then OK and it should work.

Comment: @Zhuinden...hi i installed Marketplace client, now how to search for gradle, where i have to search, plz reply

Comment: Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> search for Gradle -> install Gradle Integration Tool (not 4.4)

Comment: Thank you i can now import into eclipse, if u dnt mind how could i run this  RunAs--> build gradel?

Comment: umm I'm not going to lie, I haven't used that function when I needed Gradle, I needed it in a LibGDX project and then I could just use "run Android application" and "run Desktop application" which were options underneath the "Gradle Build" option, and it worked. I don't know if you have access to that.

Comment: oh ok..yeah i don't have access to run as android application

Comment: Also i cannot import few other gradle build projects :(

Comment: Do you have the latest ADT and Android API level 20? Not the 4.4W because that's Android Wear.

Comment: yeah i have the latest API ..tried importing 10 different projects giving different errors :(

Comment: ....errrrr I think you should post them as questions or as one different question then.

Comment: :) yeahh.. i don't know why they build android studio , gradle build  so complicated even though i installed new version of Studio and importing latest version of projects (material design samples) its giving some dependency errors, new programmers will surely get frustrated.or else its only me who is facing problem.Anyways... Thank you for the help.