# unable to run LibGDX game on android device due to not being able to find the android launcher class

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx, dex

i have an error on the logcat which reads

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

RunTime exception unable to instatiate activity componentInfo(android launcher) 
java.lang.classNotFoundException: Didn't find class " androidLauncher " on path : DexPathList[[zip file "/android-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[android-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

i shortened it down as i couldnt copy and paste it but the basic error is there 
If you need any more details just ask but hopefully this should be enough

My game compiles but doesnt run and a message pops up on my android device "game has stopped"

Hopefully someone can help as i have been messing around with this for a few days and still no luck :(

thankyou

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Did you import the project into Eclipse ADT as a "Gradle project"?

Comment: @Zhuinden yeah, theres a 'G' on all four of the folders to show this too :/ as far as i know i did that correctly

Comment: So you *did* do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031573/opening-libgdx-project-in-eclipse-adt-bundle hmm... >.< well that makes it problematic because then that is correct, did you change ANYTHING in the gradle files, or about the initial class name or anything of that sort?

Comment: @Zhuinden i tried refactoring the project to change the name so i could copy the project and make alot of changes to it, but it didnt work so i refactored it back to the original name, maybe that changed something ? but as far as i can remember thats all i changed :/

Comment: That's possible that it made some inconsistency with the build.gradle settings. I'd recommend creating a new project using the LibGDX project setup, and recreate your classes and copypaste your code from the old project to the new.

Comment: Unfortunately I personally don't see a better alternative in the given situation, although there might be a better solution, I don't know what it is, sorry.

Comment: @Zhuinden no worrys, appreciate the advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.classNotFoundException: Didn't find class " androidLauncher " on path : DexPathList[[zip file "/android-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[android-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

You seem to have changed the AndroidLauncher.java name. (notice the caps A).

- You can make a file search (Ctrl + H), with "case sensitive" checked, and change any references to this non-existing "androidApplication" class.
- Also cleaning your projects may pop these wrong references.
- Also remaking your project with the Gdx Setup, and importing your code is a 100% error proof way of fixing your problem, but may take you more time.