# Is this the most efficient way to have movement?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, performance

Ok, so at this point, I have a project setup with a canvas, surfaceview, and a bar has to move across the screen.

I have setup everything like this:

```
-Main activity class
     SurfaceView class
         -while(true) {   c.drawRect(x & y)   }  (using X, Y position)
     }
  Thread barMovement {
  while(true){  x+=1; y+=1; }
  }
}
```

Question:

So this works, but I have noticed that it's not very smooth.  Some times, the bar goes a little faster, some times its slower.

I was wondering if this method is the best way to do it?
When looking at apps like FlappyBird for example, the movement is absolutely perfect. How do they achieve this?

*Thanks,
Jason*

Comment: might want to read up on [Android Animations](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html)

Comment: Compute the position as a function of the time. And don't believe this question is no duplicate. By the way, adding 100 would make it 100 times faster... an improvement???

Comment: I understand that making it +=100 would make it faster, but I need it to be smooth as well. Making it += 100 would make it hop down the screen.

Comment: I'd rather just switch from SurfaceView to using some actual gaming framework altogether, assuming this is a game. By the way, I'm guessing in your case, the problem is that you are just saying += 1; instead of making it be determined by a velocity and as a function of time, sliced up into pieces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995854/how-to-track-time-in-libgdxandroid/23996041#23996041

Comment: Erm, i'm not familiar with OpenGL. If possible, could you guide me into the right direction? I'm somewhat new to Android.