# How to do libgdx cooldown time animation

Tags: android, animation, libgdx, loading

I have to implement a cooldown animation on a chess board with libgdx.
You can see an example on the following video: cooldown colour is yellow. A Figure has a cooldown time after each movement.
Should I use processbar or libgdx animation

[click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tb3Kpd1pDv4)

I have absolut no idea how to do it and with which source of libgdx I can do it.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Just draw a sprite (even a 1x1 `Pixmap` with a yellow pixel would be enough) with over time decreasing size.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, think about it like this: after the unit moves to a square block, you initiate a `timer` for that square block (or for the unit, and based on the unit's position you do the animation for the block. Either works.)

The timer goes from `1...0` (if you want it to be `500 ms`, then it would go from `0.5` to `0`, but at the multiplication you will normalize it up to `1` to `0` by multiplying it with `1 / 0.5` which is 2).

When you draw out the block, then if the `timer is > 0`, then you draw out a `rectangle` using a `ShapeRenderer` that begins at the `bottom corner`, up to `height_of_block * timer` (that goes from `1 to 0`).  If your drawing order is background of `square block -> yellow rectangle -> unit on top of square block`, then you will have the animation as you `update the animation by time`.

To `track time`, use the following I wrote down here: [How to track time in Libgdx(android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995854/how-to-track-time-in-libgdxandroid/23996041#23996041)

Comment: That means, I need to use Animataion to do this task? I have to make group of pictures which animate filling a rectangle?

Comment: you don't need Animation class. You basically just need a timer that runs from some time to zero, and you scale this to the [1...0] interval, and use this as a factor for the height of the rectangle you're drawing out.

Comment: what is the time 0.125f from our track time?

Comment: It's the maximum possible interval for the simulation of time. This is so that if there is a freeze then the render() call might be called too late and if that happens then you can have time skips, and this way removes it. Basically 0.125f is a constant EPSILON value.