# How to create Enemies at specific time in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am a newbie in libgdx. I am working on a game which has a player body and I have given controls but I want to create enemies at specific time in my game. I have tried creating it but only the player body is been created and but not enemy body.

This is my code

```
public class Player
    implements Screen, InputProcessor {
    private Body polybody;
    private Player player;
    private World world;
    private Body enemybody;
    private Sprite polysprite;
    public final float width, height;
    private Vector2 movement = new Vector2();
    private float speed = 580;


    public Player(World world, float x, float y, float width) {
        this.width = width; //IMP
        height = width * 2;
        BodyDef polygon = new BodyDef();
        polygon.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        polygon.position.set(x, y); //

        PolygonShape poly = new PolygonShape();
        poly.setAsBox(width / 2, height / 2); //

        //fixture defn

        FixtureDef polyfixture = new FixtureDef();
        polyfixture.shape = poly;
        polyfixture.friction = 0.8f;  //
        polyfixture.restitution = 0.1f; //
        polyfixture.density = 3; //

        //creating actual body
        polybody = world.createBody(polygon);
        polybody.createFixture(polyfixture);
        // polybody.applyAngularImpulse(52, true);
        polysprite = new Sprite(new Texture("img/car.jpg"));

        polysprite.setSize(0.5f, 1); //size of mario
        polysprite.setOrigin(polysprite.getWidth() / 2, polysprite.getHeight() / 2);
        polybody.setUserData(polysprite);

        poly.dispose();
    }


    public void update() {
        polybody.applyForceToCenter(movement, true);
    }

    public Body getBody() {
        return polybody;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    final float step = 0.1f;
    float timeElapsed = 0f;

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        timeElapsed += delta;
        while (timeElapsed > step) {
            timeElapsed -= step;
            Enemy();
        }
    }

    public void Enemy() {
        BodyDef enemy = new BodyDef();
        enemy.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        enemy.position.set(6, 3);
        PolygonShape enemypoly = new PolygonShape();
        enemypoly.setAsBox(2, 2);

        FixtureDef enemyfixture = new FixtureDef();
        enemyfixture.shape = enemypoly;
        enemyfixture.friction = 0.75f;
        enemyfixture.restitution = 0.1f;
        enemyfixture.density = 5;

        enemybody = world.createBody(enemy);
        enemybody.createFixture(enemyfixture);
        enemypoly.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (keycode) {
            case Keys.W:
                movement.y = speed;
                break;
            case Keys.S:
                movement.y = -speed;
                break;
            case Keys.D:
                movement.x = speed;
                break;
            case Keys.A:
                movement.x = -speed;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (keycode) {
            case Keys.W:
                movement.y = 0;
                break;
            case Keys.S:
                movement.y = 0;
                break;
            case Keys.D:
                movement.x = 0;
                break;
            case Keys.A:
                movement.x = 0;
        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        movement.x = speed;
        Gdx.app.log("Example", "touch done ");
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the player class that gets called first and after this on render method the enemy method gets called. The player body is working fine but I couldn't see any enemy body. Please help .Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Why do you call Enemy() each time during render()? Looks weird to me.

Comment: I just tried it so. I am not sure of what to do. Could you please guide me ? @Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your `Player` class is responsible for:

- Handling inputs for controlling the game
- the construction of enemy objects
- rendering the entire world (handling time) and displaying the world and all objects
- creating Textures (that is supposed to be created only **once**, not every time you make a `Sprite`!)

Aaaand you don't have any other class.

I think you should fix this problem.

Also, I'm a bit weary of that you're calling `dispose()` each time after you create an object.

By the way, the `render()` method only gets called if you set the active screen for the Game, so

```
public class MyGame extends Game {
    ...
    MyScreen myScreen = new MyScreen();
    ...

    public void goToMyScreen() { 
        this.setScreen(myScreen);
    }
}
```

Something like that is necessary for `render()` to work.

And please check [How to track time in Libgdx(android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995854/how-to-track-time-in-libgdxandroid/23996041#23996041) on how to handle elapsed time.

Comment: If you are new, check out these 2 tutorials on the official libgdx wiki.
[link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game)
[link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a refactoring of your application. That class `Player` doesn't look like the right place for creating enemies (which you seem to do in every step). Instead you should create the `Enemy` in the same place where you create your `Player` and give your `Enemy` an own class.

Furthermore you could write debug messages to the console or use your IDE's debugger to check what your code is actually doing.