# Splash Screen wait few seconds

Tags: java, android, wait, splash-screen

I am trying to make a splash screen wait for 10 seconds.
I tried searching everywhere and tried a few methods, but nothing seems to work.

Anyone to lead me to the right direction?

Here is my code:

```
public class SplashLoadingScreen extends Screen {

public SplashLoadingScreen(Game game) {
    super(game);
}

@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    Assets.splash= g.newImage("splash.jpg", ImageFormat.RGB565);
    game.setScreen(new LoadingScreen(game));
}

@Override
public void paint(float deltaTime) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
}

@Override
public void backButton() {
}
}
```

Comment: 10 seconds seems a long time to wait for no reason

Comment: true, yet i need it to work for 10 seconds...

Comment: 10 seconds is ridiculously long. I wouldn't play a game that makes me wait 10 seconds each time I start it. 4 seconds makes more sense. Whenever I made a splash screen, I made it clickable so that you can get past it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Handler to give the delay.

```
//handler to close the splash activity after sometime
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Call your image from assests
            }

        }, 10000);
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: handlers are android-specific and this code is for libGDX (pure java)

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23996041/2413303), you should use the `update` method to update a timer that will initiate the screen change.

```
public class SplashLoadingScreen extends Screen {

private Sprite sprite;
private Texture texture;

public SplashLoadingScreen(Game game) {
    super(game);
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/splash.png");
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    sprite = new Sprite(new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

}

private float timer = 0.0f;

@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {
    timer += deltaTime;
    if(timer > 10) {
        game.setScreen(new LoadingScreen(game));
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(float deltaTime) {
    spriteBatch.draw(sprite);
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    texture.dispose();
}

@Override
public void backButton() {
}
}
```

Comment: when ever i try to use that code for example.. i get errors.. after i import everything and add the gdx. i get error at     spriteBatch.draw(sprite); any idea what i should do?

Comment: yeah, you need to initialize the `spriteBatch` **somewhere**

Comment: I figured you've already figured out how to *draw the image on the splash screen*, as you'll need a sprite batch for that.

Comment: i did initalize the spriteBatch but i still get errors

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SplashLoadingScreen extends Screen {
public SplashLoadingScreen(Game game) {
      super(game);
}

@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {

Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
Assets.splash= g.newImage("splash.jpg", ImageFormat.RGB565);
try { 
Thread.currentThread(); 
Thread.sleep(10000); 
} catch (InterruptedException e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
game.setScreen(new LoadingScreen(game));
}

@Override
public void paint(float deltaTime) {
}


@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}


@Override
public void dispose() {
}
}
```

Comment: this seems to work.. but for some reason the Wait is working on the black screen that appears before the splash.jpg screen